# How do I share my data to others with PostGIS/QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I only started to learn using PostgreSQL with QGIS. Since I wouldn't want my local machine to be actively running PostgreSQL in the background for always-on access, is there a way to "share" or export data to my colleagues as a file format (for example, `.gpkgs` or `.shp`. I was expecting a `.db` format file)?

Or is it that SQL server does not work like that? I'm very new to the SQL server concept.

Comment: You can use pgdump to dump the entire db; you can use COPY to produce .sql files, binary files, etc.;  you can export to shapefile or any other spatial file format.  Normally you have your database running on a server that you and your colleagues can access.  One of the primary purposes of a database server is multiuser access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends how much data you want to export and what the use case looks like at hand. One thing you could do is instead of running postgres locally, run a centralized postgres that everyone has access to. This way you can create tables including geometries and your colleagues can connect to that database from their QGIS locally. If this is no option, the easiest would probably be to share files of the formate you already specified. GPKG is probably more suitable for larger amounts of data whereas shapefiles for smaller data amounts. You could of course also create dumps (more info [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/databases/db_manager.html)) but this is rather cumbersome in my opinion as you have many easier options at hand. Hope this helps?

Comment: I work with local government often, they almost only accepts "file" that they can use, and that's what the topic is about. I know how to export to other file format but just wondering if sharing db itself is not the correct thing to do. (I don't seem to find where the `.db` file is stored at anyway, like sqlite I've worked with that I can locate the file itself)

Comment: A postgres database is comprised of multiple files opposed to a sqlite db. If you want to share it, you will have to use pg_dump and the other party pg_restore, some examples can be found here https://snapshooter.com/learn/postgresql/pg_dump_pg_restore

Comment: Of course you could also archive all the database files and share them however your colleagues would have to restore them in the correct path and also make sure they have the same pg version installed. It's prone to errors this way.

Comment: It would be unusual to share the whole database with a colleague. Either have a centrally hosted always-on database that everyone can connect to and use. Or, if you're only running it on your desktop, export the tables you want to share as a file, and give that to your colleagues instead.